# Vistas Basadas en Funciones (FBV) VS. Vistas Basadas en Clases (CBV)

Tags: python, django

A la hora de crear un proyecto en Django, digamos, de relativa complejidad y tamaño, siempre me he inclinado por usar FBV ya que las encuentro más fáciles de usar. Algunos dicen que es mejor usar CBV ya que tienen algunas ventajas como por ejemplo la Herencia brindada por la POO y menos cantidad de código.

A pesar de las ventajas de las CBV todavía las encuentro un poco mas difíciles de seguir:

¿Cuáles son las ventajas de CBV sobre FBV?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yo creo que una de sus principales ventajas es la eliminación de código repetido.

Las CBV son, desde mi punto de vista, más eficientes que las vistas basadas en funciones porque reducen el código necesario para producir el resultado esperado. Esta reducción no solo agrega claridad al código, también facilitan la comprensión y el mantenimiento del mismo.

El uso de las vistas basadas en clases tiene un impacto positivo en otros elementos de la aplicación al permitir una mejor estructura de modelos y de patrones de URL, por ejemplo.

Para ilustrar las ventajas de las vistas basadas en clase, agrego un ejemplo real.

En una aplicación de control de documentos, el modelo de documentos tiene el método `get_absolute_url` que se ve así:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detalle', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

Y en el archivo `urls.py` un un patrón de búsqueda relacionada con el método anterior:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/control$', DetalleDocumento.as_view(), name='detalle'),
```

Con estos dos elementos, la vista basada en clase respectiva se reduce a lo siguiente:

```
class DetalleDocumento(DetailView):
    model = Documento
    template_name = "docs/detalle.html"
```

Y `template_name`, por cierto, es un parámetro opcional.

Esta es la principal ventaja de las CBV: el código se reduce a su mínima expresión, pero no pierde legibilidad ni eficiencia. Además las CBV funcionan en la mayoría de las situaciones, por lo que el principio DRY de Django se hace patente.

Comment: Gracias, está muy claro.

Comment: @CésarBustíos acá un recurso muy bueno para ubicarse donde queda cada cosa en las CBV https://ccbv.co.uk/